# Add empty image tag with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu with sub menus and there is a `+` and `_` image for about and close sub menus.
The problem that the menu that not have sub its align is different than other and to fix that must add image to the `li` that have no image close and open to fix the align here a screenshot for what I mean [image]

[image]

This mean is create demoniacally with js here the code I can't fix it with css because it will effect the whole menu here the code

```
$(function () {
    //this function to get , show and hide sub menu from this menu by use menu Id

    $('.daymanicPageMenu').delegate('img', 'click', function () {

        var checkSubMenuFound = $(this).parent().children(".daymanicPageSubMenu").length;

        if (checkSubMenuFound != 0) {


            //remove this div show fast
            $(this).parent().children(".daymanicPageSubMenu").slideUp("fast", function () {
                $(this).parent().children("img").attr('src', 'http://localhost:53188/Content/Images/CollectionImages/image.png');
                $(this).remove();
            });

        } else {

            $(this).parent().append("<div class='daymanicPageSubMenu'></div>");

            var subMenuDiv = $(this).parent().children(".daymanicPageSubMenu");

            //get menu Id to get sub menu by Ajax
            var menuId = $(this).data('stuff');
            // ajax request
            $.ajax({
                url: "GetSubMenu",
                data: { menuId: menuId },
                type: 'POST',
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    subMenuDiv.append(data);
                }
            });

            //show this div fast
            subMenuDiv.hide().slideDown("fast", function () {
                $(this).parent().children("img").attr('src', 'http://localhost:53188/Content/Images/CollectionImages/image2.png');
            });

        }

    });


    //List Indexing function
    $('.listIndexing').delegate('label', 'click', function () {

        var currentpage = $('.liIndexing').html();

        var parent = $(this).parent();
        var parentParent = parent.parent();
        var removeClassLabel = parentParent.find('li[name=' + currentpage + ']');
        removeClassLabel.children('label').removeClass("liIndexing");

        if ($(this).html() == "Next") {

            currentpage++;
            var pagecount = $(this).attr('name');
        }
        else if ($(this).html() == "Prev") {
            currentpage--;
        } else {
            currentpage = $(this).data('stuff');
        }
        if (currentpage < 1) { currentpage = 1; }
        if (currentpage > pagecount) { currentpage = pagecount; }

        //get list Id to get List News by Ajax
        var newListdiv = $("#newsPage");

        // ajax request
        $.ajax({
            url: "News",
            data: { listId: currentpage },
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                newListdiv.empty().append(data);
            }
        });
        var addClassLabel = parentParent.find('li[name=' + currentpage + ']');
        addClassLabel.children('label').addClass("liIndexing");


    });
    $("#newsPageListIndex li:eq( 1 )").children("label").addClass("liIndexing");


var tn1 = $('.mygallery').tn3({
    skinDir:"skins",
    imageClick:"fullscreen",
    image:{
        maxZoom:1.5,
        crop:true,
        clickEvent:"dblclick",
        transitions:[{
            type:"blinds"
        },{
            type:"grid"
        },{
            type:"grid",
            duration:460,
            easing:"easeInQuad",
            gridX:1,
            gridY:8,
            // flat, diagonal, circle, random
            sort:"random",
            sortReverse:false,
            diagonalStart:"bl",
            // fade, scale
            method:"scale",
            partDuration:360,
            partEasing:"easeOutSine",
            partDirection:"left"
        }]
    }
});

});
```

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: English is not my native so no need to make fun if need more information ask me or see the screen shot photo

Comment: @user974946 We are not making fun of anybody but just trying to help people. For that we need to understand what exactly is the issue you are facing.

Comment: Exactly. A jsfiddle example would help very much.

Comment: You see the screen shot the li that not have image for collapse the li is on the left not align with the li that have collapse image (+ and -) so its have to be empty image inside it to to be in same align with all li

Comment: here example http://jsfiddle.net/W2ud7/

Answer (score 0):

> to fix the align I must add image to the li

You, you don't need to. Use CSS for aligning them properly. Also, for a nested list menu you should actually nest list elements.